# Can't detect whether Session variable exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to determine if a `Session` variable exists, but I'm getting the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Code:

```
    // Check if the "company_path" exists in the Session context
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"].ToString() != null)
    {
        // Session exists, set it
        company_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // Session doesn't exist, set it to the default
        company_path = "/reflex/SMD";
    }
```

That is because the `Session` name "company_path" doesn't exist, but I can't detect it!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do not use ToString() if you want to check if Session["company_path"] is null. As `if Session["company_path"] is null then Session["company_path"].ToString() will give you exception.`

**Change**

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"].ToString() != null)
{
    company_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"].ToString();
}
else
{
    company_path = "/reflex/SMD";
}
```

**To**

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"]!= null)
{
      company_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"].ToString();
}
else
{
      company_path = "/reflex/SMD";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still getting the same error though with that

Comment: Check if your current thread can access  System.Web.HttpContext?

Comment: How do I check that?  I have `using System.Web`?  Is this right?

Comment: Is it your aspx page code behind or some class in your library?

Comment: It's a class in my App_Code folder.  Is there a special way that I need to give it access?  I want to avoid having to pass the variable in my constructor.  Thanks :)

Comment: You can access in App_Code. I confirmed it by test again.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved as a one liner in the latest version of .NET using a null-conditional `?.` and a null-coalesce `??`:

```
// Check if the "company_path" exists in the Session context
company_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"]?.ToString() ?? "/reflex/SMD";
```

Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Answer (score 0):

If deploying on Azure (as of August 2017), it is useful to also check if the Session keys array is populated, e.g.:

```
Session.Keys.Count > 0 && Session["company_path"]!= null
```